# how to setup the toaster yocto local setup

Tags: yocto, build-system

I have tried so many methods to setup `yocto toaster local set-up`, but I did not completed. Please tell the procedure *how to setup the local yocto toaster setup*.

I observed , in web interface every time when I compile a recipe with modifications , the `toaster` serching the rcipe from web and doing git hard reset then compiling so what I do not require web interface I need to all recipes compilation with `local repo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto `poky/bitbake/lib/toaster/bldcontrol` and open the file `localhostbecontroller.py` then search for `git reset --hard`.

remove the word `--hard` from the file. then its should look like below

```
self._shellcmd('git fetch --all && git reset "%s"' % ref, localdirname)
```

After this you can restart your toaster.

Comment: Thanks@Sivanageswararo, same I have done its working fine . but i believe its workaround . Is there any other geniric method.